# SharePoint webpart for WebEx

Tags: sharepoint, webpart, webex

Is there a SharePoint webpart available for WebEx?  We do a lot of web conferencing and want the functionality to be exposed through SharePoint but WebEx hasn't released a webpart yet.

The solution provided by WebEx [has its critics](http://seattlemcse.blogspot.com/2008/09/webex-and-sharepoint.html).
I searched for 'SharePoint' in [Cisco's WebEx knowledgebase](http://support.webex.com/SelfServiceWeb/SelfServicePortal.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=KnowledgeBaseHome) and got back zero (0) results.

Has anyone found either a workaround or maybe a third-party webpart?

Answer (score -1):

I never used WebEx but what I can understand, this is not recommended.

I would use OCS (Office Communication Server). I used this one, really easy to use and has a bunch of functionnality. You may, then, import your conference report on sharepoint maybe easier than from Webex.

Take a look at it, this is just a simple advice.

Regards,
David.

Comment: We will have to look into that.  In the meantime, we've been using WebEx for quite awhile and it would be hard to justify a switch while we are moving to SharePoint.

Comment: Of course, justify that change will need more work. But I'd test it out in en Lab.Environnment just to compare and check functionalities. It's now up to you! 

I've been working with OCS for severals months and as I told you, I don't remember if you can import stuff from OCS onto WSS. But for sure, for live meeting, this is an asset!